# how to create a default message in PFQueryTableViewController when no objects found

Tags: uitableview, parse-platform, ios8

I am looking to use the Parse PFQueryTableViewController to display a list of items stored in cloud.

However, when there are no items, I am looking to show a default Message in the tableview via a customized tableview cell that says "No Item Found".

I am looking for inputs on how  customize the PFQueryTableViewController to achieve this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's doable with some additional method overriding and a little trickery.  I would add that (imo) we're straying into territory where the net benefit of the parse.com specialization of the iOS class is reduced.

```
// lie about the actual count
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (self.objects.count) return [super tableView:tableView numberOfRowsInSection:section];
    return 1;
}

// answer a dummy object when there are none
- (PFObject *)objectAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (self.objects.count) return [super objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    return [PFObject objectWithClassName:[self parseClassName]];
}

// change how we behave for the dummy object
- (PFUI_NULLABLE PFTableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFUI_NULLABLE PFObject *)object {

    // check for your dummy object (it will be the only one with no id
    // return a special cell in that case
    if (!object.objectId) {
        // create and return the special custom cell here
        // if you're unsure about this, [see this SO answer][1]
    } else {
        PFTableViewCell *cell;
        // the regular cellForRowAtIndexPath behavior goes here
        return cell;
    }
}
```

In terms of cost-benefit of the specialized subclass, I feel the same way even about UITableViewController.  The most control (and not that much extra work) can be had with a regular UIViewController containing a table view.

Comment: thanks for the workaround..I will try it out..I take it that it is better to customize a standard uitableviewcontroller to achieve the above outcome.